# Is there any way to enforce a restriction on class and its super class using ArchUnit Test?

Tags: archunit

I want to enforce a restriction such that methods present in a class that is annotated with Singleton and its SuperClass should not return dataType `java.util.date`.

Below is the class structure

```
public interface Demo {

default Date print(){
     return new Date(23456);
  }
}

 

@Singleton
public class Test implements Demo{

public void print(){
     System.out.println("Some string")
  }
}

public class AnotherClass implements Demo{

public void doSomething(){
     System.out.println("do Something")
  }
}
```

```
Below is my ArchUnit Test

methods().that().areDeclaredInClassesThat().areAnnotatedWith(Singleton.class)
.should().notHaveRawReturnType(Date.class);
```

The above test case does not show any violations because it does not consider the method declared in the interface which is implemented by Test Class.

Is there any way by which it will also consider the superclass method as well?

I tried With Java Reflection API Demo.Class.getMethods(), this API considers super class methods as well. I want to achieve the same behavior with ArchUnit

Comment: Technically, the method is not present on the class, but only on the interface. Just an assumption, but I don't think ArchUnit supports (detects?) such default methods at the moment. Maybe you need to write your own rule/condition which walks the inheritance hierarchy and checks default methods of interfaces too

Comment: The question isn't related to `junit-jupiter`. Please remove that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default method is not declared in `Test` (but in `Demo`), therefore no violation is caught when testing `methods().that().areDeclaredInClassesThat().areAnnotatedWith(Singleton.class)`.
Such a test wouldn't catch a non-default method inhertited from a superclass like in the following example either:

```java
class Demo {
    Date getDate() {
        return new Date(23456);
    }
}

@Singleton
class Test extends Demo {
}
```

If you want to cover declared and inherited methods, you can (as [suggested by `knittl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76986337/is-there-any-way-to-enforce-a-restriction-on-class-and-its-super-class-using-arc#comment135716861_76986337)) use a custom condition (but you can at least use [`getAllRawInterfaces()`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/1.1.0/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaClass.html#getAllRawInterfaces()) and [`getAllRawSuperclasses()`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/1.1.0/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaClass.html#getAllRawSuperclasses()) – or their convenient combination [`getAllClassesSelfIsAssignableTo()`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/1.1.0/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaClass.html#getAllClassesSelfIsAssignableTo()), which also includes the class itself – to *walk the inheritance hierarchy):*

```java
import static com.tngtech.archunit.base.DescribedPredicate.describe;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.conditions.ArchConditions.have;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.conditions.ArchConditions.not;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition.classes;
import static java.util.stream.Stream.concat;

// ...

    classes()
    .that().areAnnotatedWith(Singleton.class)
    .should(not(have(describe("or inherit methods returning Date", javaClass ->
        javaClass.getAllClassesSelfIsAssignableTo().stream()
            .map(JavaClass::getMethods)
            .flatMap(Set::stream)
            .anyMatch(m -> m.getRawReturnType().isEquivalentTo(Date.class))
    ))));
```

(ArchUnit detects default methods of interfaces without a problem.)

Comment: Thanks Manfred for Answer.
Meanwhile I figured out one more solution.

methods().that().areDeclaredInClassesThat().areAnnotatedWith(Singleton.class).or()
.areDeclaredInClassesThat().areAssignableFrom(new DescribedPredicate<>("Return type should not be Date") {


@Override
public boolean test(JavaClass javaClass) {

return javaClass.isAnnotatedWith(Singleton.class);

}

}).should().notHaveRawReturnType(Date.class);

Comment: @Codinggeek, solution can be simplified in two ways: 1. You can use the predefined predicate `CanBeAnnotated.Predicates.annotatedWith`. 2. Classes that annotated `@Singleton` are also assignable from a class annotated with `@Singleton`. So the short version is: `methods().that().areDeclaredInClassesThat().areAssignableFrom(annotatedWith(Singleton.class)).should().notHaveRawReturnType(Date.class)`. But I wouldn't prefer this solution because it records the `Date`-returning method as violation, whereas my feeling is that the problem is the `@Singleton`-annotated class.